# horizontally auto scroll to active thumbnail li

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoscroll

i have horizontal book page image thumbnail ul li, more than 100 image, i have given text box to enter page number to active that page and view that page, it is working without any problem but it is not auto scrolling to that active li in ul, i'm beginner to JavaScript please help me with this, bellowis my code

**HTML**

```
   <div class="book-list-headbox">
       <div class="page-number-box">
           <label for="" id="total-page" value="" class="mb-0"></label>
           <span class="separator">of</span>
           <input type="text" id="current-page" value="1">
       </div>
   </div>

  <ul class="book-list" id="book-list">
        <?php if ($total_page > 0) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($results as $row) : ?>
        <li class="book">
            <span class="page-number" id="active-page-number"><?php echo $page_num++ ?></span>
            <img src="<?php echo PAGE_URL . "/" . $b_id . "/" . $row->page_name ?>" alt="Book Page">
        </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif ?>
  </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var bookCurrentPages = $('.book #active-page-number');
$('#current-page').keypress(function(e) { 
    var userInput = $('#current-page').val();
    if (this.value.length == 0 && e.which == 48){
        // disable enter zero
        return false;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        bookCurrentPages.each(function (key) {
            var numKey = key + 1;
            if (userInput == numKey) {
                // console.log(numKey + " success");
                var currentKey = userInput;   
                // console.log(currentKey);
                $('#book-list li:nth-child('+ currentKey +')').children('img').trigger('click');
            }
        })
    return false; // prevent the button click from happening
    }
});
```

**Demo**
check my codes,
https://jsfiddle.net/Looper/dmug0zxz/1/

Comment: Try to provide a live example, need to add `html` `css` too.

Comment: Have something in my mind, but need to see your html first

Comment: i have added my html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
 li{display: table-cell; padding:20px;}
 ul{display: table-row; }
 .cont{overflow: auto;}
 li.active{border: 1px solid blue;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="book-list-headbox">
       <div class="page-number-box">
           <label for="" id="total-page" value="" class="mb-0"></label>
           <span class="separator">of</span>
           <input type="text" id="current-page" value="1">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cont">
  <ul class="book-list" id="book-list">
        <li class="book active"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=1" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=2" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=3" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=4" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=5" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=6" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=7" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=8" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=9" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=11" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=12" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=13" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=14" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=15" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=16" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=17" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=18" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=19" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=20" alt="Book Page"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <div>another content</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(function(){
  $('#current-page').change(function() {
   var i = $(this).val() -1;
   activeBook(i);
  });
  $('.book-list').on('click', '.book', function(){
   activeBook($(this).index());
  });
  
  function activeBook(i){
   $('.book').removeClass('active');
   var active = $('.book').eq(i).addClass('active');
   var left = active.position().left;
   var currScroll= $(".cont").scrollLeft(); 
   var contWidth = $('.cont').width()/2; 
   var activeOuterWidth = active.outerWidth()/2; 
   left= left + currScroll - contWidth + activeOuterWidth;

   $('.cont').animate( { 
    scrollLeft: left
   },'slow');
  }
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is what i expected, thank you ill try and let u know

Comment: i made it before you post your fiddle. i will help you figure out your current fiddle only if i have extra time again. good luck.

Comment: yah please can u fix that, coz i was trying to merge your code with mine, im getting problems

Comment: as i said i'm learning java script , the above jsfiddle codes are my own idea, tell me if there is any wrong or how it is different from your code, coz your code is less than mine

Comment: thank you very much mate, but next arrow not working i dont know why

Comment: hey mate, there is one problem, if we enter the value, it is scrolling that li and active it, but it is not taking and displaying that src of that img?

Comment: thank you very much for your time and work, some part of codes bit confusing to me, but ill try to understand it, happy code!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161936/discussion-between-plonknimbuzz-and-looper).

Comment: click link `continue this discussion in chat`, dont reply here again, since your question is already solved

Comment: @plonknimbuzz Thank you...this is very helpful for my project....would it be possible to feed a custom index...as currently the index is set to 1 to n...the thumbnail gallery that I have has its own numbers attached to it

Answer (score 0):

One can use jquery's scrollTop on window to do some scrolling:

```
$(window).scrollLeft($('#book-list li:nth-child('+ currentKey +')').scrollLeft())
```

You can have a look at scrollLeft function here: [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/)

In addition, you can do some cool trick for smooth scrolling by this:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollLeft: xxx})
```

Comment: it is not working, it is not even activating li if i enter page number

Comment: my bad it is activating that i entered page num but not scrolling, scrolling not working

Comment: @Looper I am building a jsfiddle to show you what I meant. Please give me a sec

Comment: scrollTop() for vertical scroll position, but i asked horizontal scroll:[

Comment: @Looper I am sorry for misreading that. You can use scrollLeft instead for horizontal scroll

Comment: @Looper might provide me a jsfiddle of what you have tried?

Comment: i have added my jsfid u can understand now,