# Javascript retain the horizontal scroll bar position on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a horizontal thumbnail scroll bar on my webpage and I am using the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966545/horizontally-auto-scroll-to-active-thumbnail-li) to scroll to a particular image in the thumbnail gallery.  However, when I reload the page with F5, the gallery returns to the first image location.  This becomes a problem since my thumbnail gallery has around 7500 images.

I have modified this code by adding an addEventListener to the window onload and retained the last clicked thumbnail as the index value in localStorage.  On window onload, I am using the index to push the scroller to the last clicked image location.  But it doesn;t work, nor i am getting any errors.  The modified code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  li{display: table-cell; padding:20px;}
  ul{display: table-row; }
  .cont{overflow: auto;}
  li.active{border: 1px solid blue;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="book-list-headbox">
       <div class="page-number-box">
           <label for="" id="total-page" value="" class="mb-0"></label>
           <span class="separator">of</span>
           <input type="text" id="current-page" value="1">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cont">
  <ul class="book-list" id="book-list">
        <li class="book active"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=1" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=2" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=3" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=4" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=5" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=6" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=7" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=8" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=9" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=11" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=12" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=13" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=14" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=15" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=16" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=17" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=18" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=19" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=20" alt="Book Page"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <div>another content</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $('#current-page').change(function() {
      var i = $(this).val() -1;
      activeBook(i);
      localStorage.setItem('clicki', i);

    });
    $('.book-list').on('click', '.book', function(){
      activeBook($(this).index());
    });

    function activeBook(i){
      $('.book').removeClass('active');
      var active = $('.book').eq(i).addClass('active');
      var left = active.position().left;
      var currScroll= $(".cont").scrollLeft(); 
      var contWidth = $('.cont').width()/2; 
      var activeOuterWidth = active.outerWidth()/2; 
      left= left + currScroll - contWidth + activeOuterWidth;


      $('.cont').animate( { 
        scrollLeft: left
      },'slow');
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    $(function(){
    $('#current-page').change(function() { //I tried changing this to onload function
      var clicki = localStorage.getItem('clicki');
      alert(clicki); //This alert also doesn't work.
      var i = clicki;
      activeBook(i);
    });
    $('.book-list').on('click', '.book', function(){
      activeBook($(this).index());
    });

    function activeBook(i){
      $('.book').removeClass('active');
      var active = $('.book').eq(i).addClass('active');
      var left = active.position().left;
      var currScroll= $(".cont").scrollLeft(); 
      var contWidth = $('.cont').width()/2; 
      var activeOuterWidth = active.outerWidth()/2; 
      left= left + currScroll - contWidth + activeOuterWidth;


      $('.cont').animate( { 
        scrollLeft: left
      },'slow');
    }
  });
  })

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like that:

1. Set a variable on your onLoad listner and put 0 (the first photo) or your `localStorage.getItem('clicki')` if is > 0 (or true)
2. Then use `activeBook(clicki);`.

Try it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  li{display: table-cell; padding:20px;}
  ul{display: table-row; }
  .cont{overflow: auto;}
  li.active{border: 1px solid blue;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="book-list-headbox">
       <div class="page-number-box">
           <label for="" id="total-page" value="" class="mb-0"></label>
           <span class="separator">of</span>
           <input type="text" id="current-page" value="1">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cont">
  <ul class="book-list" id="book-list">
        <li class="book active"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=1" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=2" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=3" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=4" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=5" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=6" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=7" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=8" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=9" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=11" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=12" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=13" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=14" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=15" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=16" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=17" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=18" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=19" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=20" alt="Book Page"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <div>another content</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>


  $(function(){

    $('#current-page').change(function() {
      setStorage($(this).val() -1)
    });


    $('.book-list').on('click', '.book', function(){
      setStorage($(this).index())
    });

  });

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var clicki = (localStorage.getItem('clicki')) ? (localStorage.getItem('clicki')) : 0 ;
      // alert(clicki);
      activeBook(clicki);
  });


  function setStorage(myNum){
    localStorage.setItem('clicki', myNum);
    activeBook(myNum);
  }

  function activeBook(i){
    $('.book').removeClass('active');
    var active = $('.book').eq(i).addClass('active');
    var left = active.position().left;
    var currScroll= $(".cont").scrollLeft(); 
    var contWidth = $('.cont').width()/2; 
    var activeOuterWidth = active.outerWidth()/2; 
    left= left + currScroll - contWidth + activeOuterWidth;


    $('.cont').animate( { 
      scrollLeft: left
    },'slow');
  }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS**: I created a function to set localStorage also when you click on img. Remove it, if it is not important for you.

Answer (score 1):

Below code will satisfy your needs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  li{display: table-cell; padding:20px;}
  ul{display: table-row; }
  .cont{overflow: auto;}
  li.active{border: 1px solid blue;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="book-list-headbox">
       <div class="page-number-box">
           <label for="" id="total-page" value="" class="mb-0"></label>
           <span class="separator">of</span>
           <input type="text" id="current-page" value="1">
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="cont">
  <ul class="book-list" id="book-list">
        <li class="book active"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=1" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=2" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=3" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=4" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=5" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=6" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=7" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=8" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=9" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=10" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=11" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=12" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=13" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=14" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=15" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=16" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=17" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=18" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=19" alt="Book Page"></li>
        <li class="book"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300/?text=20" alt="Book Page"></li>
  </ul>
</div>

  <div>another content</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $('#current-page').change(function() {
      var i = $(this).val() -1;
      activeBook(i);
      localStorage.setItem('clicki', i);

    });
    $('.book-list').on('click', '.book', function(){
      activeBook($(this).index());
    });

    function activeBook(i){
      $('.book').removeClass('active');
      var active = $('.book').eq(i).addClass('active');
      var left = active.position().left;
      var currScroll= $(".cont").scrollLeft(); 
      var contWidth = $('.cont').width()/2; 
      var activeOuterWidth = active.outerWidth()/2; 
      left= left + currScroll - contWidth + activeOuterWidth;


      $('.cont').animate( { 
        scrollLeft: left
      },'slow');
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var clicki = localStorage.getItem('clicki');
      var i = clicki;
      activeBook(i);

    $('.book-list').on('click', '.book', function(){
      activeBook($(this).index());
    });

    function activeBook(i){
        $('#current-page').val(i);
      $('.book').removeClass('active');
      var active = $('.book').eq(i).addClass('active');
      var left = active.position().left;
      var currScroll= $(".cont").scrollLeft(); 
      var contWidth = $('.cont').width()/2; 
      var activeOuterWidth = active.outerWidth()/2; 
      left= left + currScroll - contWidth + activeOuterWidth;


      $('.cont').animate( { 
        scrollLeft: left
      },'slow');
    }
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I just changed your code to `window load`.
So it triggers automatically when `window load` successfully.
Tried to save this as one single html file and run in `apache server` you will get what you expected.

Comment: @Apricot if you are happy please mark this as answer.